# Deciphering a kanji from a mug

Tags: kanji

Oh dear.  I know much this site hates these sorts of things.  Sigh.  Here I go.

OK.  I have a mug which a friend gave to me many long years ago.  They weren't Japanese; they just thought it was a nice mug and figured I could read it.  Which at the time, I couldn't.  Here are four pictures showing the written text.

[image: かち]
[image: 読めない漢字]
[image: ことは]
[image: 仲よき]

I can actually read most of this: 仲よきことは？しきかち。

I have some guesses for the kanji I can't read:  美しい or 楽しい.  In fact, a web search brings up the following

> 仲よきことは美しきかな

But I'm not sure that that character really looks anything like 美.  I'm just guessing at 楽.

What say you all?

Comment: 「仲よきことは美しきかな」 is almost certainly what it is.  I have a painting with this phrase on it too (although it's preceded by 「いつの日も」.

Comment: is the かな rhetoric?

Comment: @istrasci So are you saying my reading of the last kana is incorrect?  It looks like a ち more than な to me.  And wouldn't かち give a different sense than かな?

Comment: 「な」の変体仮名ですね。　http://www.benricho.org/kana/na.html　これ→　http://www.benricho.org/kana/kana-img/f4f0.gif

Comment: @Chocolate Oh wow.  Indeed.  Thank you.  Is there a similar sight for looking up kanji, such as 楽?

Comment: Wiktionaryとか・・　https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A5%BD　「楽」「異体字」でググると何か見つかるかも。(でも、この写真の湯呑には「仲よきことは美しきかな」って書いてありますね、istrasciさんの言うように。最初の2 strokes が大きくかかれてるんです)

Comment: @Chocolate That's extremely helpful.  Thank you.  And, I learned a new word, 湯‌​呑.  What a great word!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, I may as well add this as an answer now.

「仲よきことは美しきかな」 is almost certainly what it is.  This appears to be a well-known phrase, and it matches this print I have (although it's preceded by 「いつの日も」) .

[image: phrase]

Sometimes the 「かな」is written with the kanji 哉.  Also, as pointed out by @chocolateさん, the [な on your cup is a 変体仮名](http://www.benricho.org/kana/na.html) which is why it's kind of looks like ち.

Comment: such an interesting picture. any idea what the picture means: like, why is there a snake there?

Comment: No clue.  It was a present I received from my Japanese teacher probably 15 years ago.

Comment: well, it's very nice. thank you for sharing.

Comment: 干支がヘビ年だったとか・・・？ヘビの絵って、よくヘビ年に飾ってあるような気がする。なんか、絵馬も描いてあっておめでたい雰囲気。その巾着の中身はもちろんかな...?

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks for the explanation.  That totally makes sense, and so many clues to that too.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If their the "printed" form (I don't know the japanese word for it) you can use [辞書{じしょ}](https://www.jisho.org) to either try to draw it or pick out components. I don't know if it can identify calligraphy like that though.